# Why does git branch -v produce different output for -a --no-merged options

Tags: git, git-branch

I took a quick look at local and remote unmerged branches in an untidy repo.  The output was like so:

```
$ git branch -a --no-merged
  staging
  userupdate
  remotes/origin/emailsetup
  remotes/origin/feature/AFPSH-187
  remotes/origin/hashpassword
  remotes/origin/mergemailer
  remotes/origin/userupdate
```

Then I checked the verbose output, and I was surprised to see a different, longer set of results.

```
$ git branch -av --no-merged
  staging                          21026a6 [behind 0] updated staging server
  userupdate                       7363a5c file name fixing
  remotes/origin/emailsetup        b6d4094 Merge branch 'dev' into emailsetup
  remotes/origin/feature/AFPSH-187 47e6bdd Merge branch 'plannercontent' into fe
  remotes/origin/hashpassword      7b24f6b AFPSH-51 - Remove set password 
  remotes/origin/master            0f9f7ed all starting files
  remotes/origin/mergemailer       c9a8281 AFPSH-218 - Fix Expiration mailer met
  remotes/origin/originalfiles     0f9f7ed all starting files
  remotes/origin/staging           5112f1b latest deployment
  remotes/origin/userupdate        299e722 further merge fixing
```

Further info:

- All the extra branches that appear in the verbose output also appear in the lists for `git branch -a --merged`.
- The list for `git branch -av --merged` is also longer than the list for `git branch -a --merged`, but this appears to only include branches with identical heads
- `git branch -av --merged` does not include any results from `git branch -a --unmerged`
- `git branch -av --merged` does include some results from the additional branches in `git branch -av --unmerged`, and those commits have the same hashes and messages in both lists
- `git --version` yields `1.8.3.msysgit.0`

---

What is the reason for these differences?

Comment: What version of git are you using?

Comment: Can you try again with the latest realease? (https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/tag/Git-1.9.2-preview20140411). Uncompress the archive where you want: no need to modify your current git: https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/download/Git-1.9.2-preview20140411/PortableGit-1.9.2-preview20140411.7z

Comment: Same results with 1.9.2.msysgit.0